# currentAccessToken()->delete throw exception on test but works fine in real

Tags: php, laravel, testing, laravel-sanctum

- Sanctum Version: `^2.11.2`
- Laravel Version: `8.54`
- PHP Version: `7.3|^8.0`
- Database Driver & Version:

#### Description:

deleting current user token works fine
but in test it throw exception

#### Steps To Reproduce:

`routes/api.php`

```php
Route::prefix('auth')->middleware('auth:sanctum')->group(function () {
    Route::delete('/sign_out', [AuthController::class, 'signOut']);
   /// other routes
});
```

`app\Http\Controllers\Api\Auth\AuthController.php`

```php
//  * delete the current access token
    public function signOut(Request $request)
    {
        $request->user()->currentAccessToken()->delete();
        return  response()->json(
            [
                'message' => 'auth.signed_out_successfully'
            ],
        );
    }
```

the test

```php
  public function test_when_signed_out_the_token_gets_deleted()
    {

        // * create new user
        User::factory()->create(['email' => 'max@zod.com']);

        // * sign in the user
        $response = $this->withHeaders(
            ['accept' => 'Application/json']
        )->postJson('/api/auth/sign_in', [
            'email' => 'max@zod.com',
            'password' => 'top_secret',
            'device_name' => 'test_device'
        ]);
        $response->assertStatus(200);
        $object = $response->getData();
        $array = json_decode(json_encode($object), true);
        $token = $array['data']['token'];


        /// get current tokens count from the server
        $queryResult  = DB::select('select Count(*) from personal_access_tokens')[0];
        $array = json_decode(json_encode($queryResult), true);
        $tokensCount = $array["Count(*)"];
        $this->assertEquals("1", $tokensCount);


        // * sign out request
        $response = $this->withHeaders(
            [
                'accept' => 'Application/json',
                'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token,
            ]
        )->delete('/api/auth/sign_out');
        dd($response->getData());
        $response->assertStatus(200);


        /// get current tokens count from the server
        $queryResult  = DB::select('select Count(*) from personal_access_tokens')[0];
        $array = json_decode(json_encode($queryResult), true);
        $tokensCount = $array["Count(*)"];
        $this->assertEquals("0", $tokensCount);
    }
```

stack trace

```
{
  "message": "Call to undefined method Laravel\Sanctum\TransientToken::delete()",
  "exception": "Error",
  "file": "<path>\app\Http\Controllers\Api\Auth\AuthController.php",
}
```

Comment: Laravel test should not call the application more than once, as the app lifecycle has been started and bootstrapped

Comment: could you explain more ?

Comment: You should create all the data you need for a single api call. So create your access token or use actingAs() instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the problem is with your `login` API endpoint.

Do not use `Auth` or `auth()` methods to implement your login. For example, DO NOT implement with `auth()->attempt($credentials)`.

Your `login` API should be:

- Find the user record (ex. `User::where('email', request()->email)->first()`);
- Check the password
  with `Hash::check(request()->password, $user->password)`;
- Return a
  token with `$user->createToken('something')->plainTextToken`.

If you use `Auth` for your login, you are using the "web" guard, even if not explicitly defined. The web guard is made for cookie-based authentication, not for tokens.

Also, explicitly use the `sanctum` guard on all `Auth` calls. Ex. `auth('sanctum')->user()`.

### Why this exception happens?

This exception means `currentAccessToken()` is returning a `TransientToken` object instead of `PersonalAccessToken`.

The `TransientToken` is returned when Sanctum detects a cookie-based authentication. It is not a database record and doesn't have a `delete()` method.

The `PersonalAccessToken` is returned on token-based authentication. It is an Eloquent record and can be deleted.

### Why does it only happens in tests?

The way Sanctum detects if it is a cookie or token authentication is by checking `auth('web')->user()`.

If there is a user in the "web" guard, it is a cookie-based authentication. If there's no user, it is a token-based authentication.

The "web" guard is made to be used with cookies and session middlewares. It doesn't work properly without them and shouldn't be used on APIs.

Your code works in a server because `auth('web')->user()` returns null. But in testing, because your login API call sets a user to `auth('web')->user()`, the next API call will have the user loaded, and Sanctum treats it as a cookie-based authorization.

### Alternative solution for login in tests

No matter what, you should never use the "web" guard in a code that is token-based. Make sure you explicitly specify the "sanctum" (or whatever non-session guard) on `auth` calls. Ex.: `auth('sanctum')->user()`.

That said, you have an alternative for login in tests.

In tests, you can replace your login calls with `Sanctum::actingAs($user)` or `actingAs($user, 'sanctum')`. Just make sure to specify the Sanctum guard.

If you are testing tokens, I recommend making an API call to login instead of authenticating with "actingAs". Otherwise, you won't be testing in the same way as in real life and may not catch some errors.

Answer (score 0):

I face the same problem, application work fine but failed in test. I resolve this by editing `config/sanctum.php`:

origin:

```php
[
    'guard' => ['web'],
]
```

change to following:

```php
[
    'guard' => [],  // clear this config array
]
```

As other answers say, the default guard is `web`, but we use Sanctum as api token. The point is don't use `web` guard.

The following text is from `config/sanctum.php` comments:

> If none of these guards are able to authenticate the request, Sanctum will use the bearer token that's present on an incoming request for authentication.

Therefore, just remove the guard and leave it empty.

---

BTW, in other test should use `actingAs()` is correct, but login test, should simulate how user act. I agree the test content of this post.